# Create wordcloud d3.js from elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, elasticsearch, word-cloud

I am using the following example as base and want to make it dynamic word cloud https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud

```
define(['scripts/d3.v3', 'scripts/elasticsearch'], function (d3, elasticsearch) {

"use strict";
var client = new elasticsearch.Client();

client.search({
    index: 'nfl',
    size: 5,
    body: {
        // Begin query.
        query: {
            // Boolean query for matching and excluding items.
            bool: {
                must: { match: { "description": "TOUCHDOWN" }},
                must_not: { match: { "qtr": 5 }}
            }
        },
        // Aggregate on the results
        aggs: {
            touchdowns: {
                terms: {
                    field: "qtr",
                    order: { "_term" : "asc" }
                }
            }
        }
        // End query.
    }
}).then(function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);

        // D3 code goes here.
        var touchdowns = resp.aggregations.touchdowns.buckets;

        // d3 donut chart
        var width = 600,
            height = 300,
            radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

        var color = ['#ff7f0e', '#d62728', '#2ca02c', '#1f77b4'];

        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .outerRadius(radius - 60)
            .innerRadius(120);

        var pie = d3.layout.pie()
            .sort(null)
            .value(function (d) { return d.doc_count; });

        var svg = d3.select("#donut-chart").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/1.4 + "," + height/2 + ")");

        var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
            .data(pie(touchdowns))
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "arc");

        g.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .style("fill", function (d, i) {
                return color[i];
            });

        g.append("text")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("fill", "white")
            .text(function (d) { return d.data.key; });
});
```

this is example code from elasticsearch website how to use with d3

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="../lib/d3/d3.js"></script>
<script src="../d3.layout.cloud.js"></script>
<script>
  var fill = d3.scale.category20();
  d3.layout.cloud().size([300, 300])
      .words([
        "Hello", "world", "normally", "you", "want", "more", "words",
        "than", "this"].map(function(d) {
        return {text: d, size: 10 + Math.random() * 90};
      }))
      .padding(5)
      .rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .font("Impact")
      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .on("end", draw)
      .start();
  function draw(words) {
    d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", 300)
        .attr("height", 300)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(150,150)")
      .selectAll("text")
        .data(words)
      .enter().append("text")
        .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.size + "px"; })
        .style("font-family", "Impact")
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return fill(i); })
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")";
        })
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
  }
</script>
```

This is code from d3 jason davies about wordcloud

How to make d3 wordcloud to listen data from elasticsearch ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to get the elasticsearch response data into a format that's easy to pass into the wordcloud sample code, something like this:

```
var data = [{
    "text": "How",
    "size": 20
}, {
    "text": "to",
    "size": 30
}, ... ]
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/henbox/RUTpJ/659/

The response you get back from your Elasticsearch aggregation will look something like this:

[image: es response]

You'll also see this in a console when the ES response is logged:

```
}).then(function (resp) {
  console.log(resp);
  ...
```

So to manipulate that data, add:

```
var data = resp.aggregations.myaggregation.buckets.map(function(d) {
  return {
    text: d.key,
    size: d.doc_count
  };
});
```

Note that `myaggregation` is a name you will define. In your NFL example code above it's actually called `touchdowns`

Pushing this data straight into the wordcloud will cause problems, however. In the wordcloud example, the `font-size` is determined directly from the size, but there's a good chance your `doc_count`s are much too high, and will need to be scaled down.

For that, try D3 linear scale. In this case, it will scale the range of input values down to a value between 15 and 100, which can be used for font size:

```
var fontsize = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {return d.size}))
  .range([15, 100]);
```

Then, instead of

```
.style("font-size", function (d) {
  return d.size + "px";
})
```

use:

```
.style("font-size", function (d) {
  return fontsize(d.size) + "px";
})
```

Comment: now i done what you ask me for and its working :) , but why this image coming out ,http://s4.postimg.org/no5jzve59/rere.png

Comment: That's odd. Looks like the text you're trying to display is actually an object. If you change: `.text(function(d) { return d.text; });` to `.text(function(d) { console.log(d.text); return d.text; });`you'll be able to see what that object is in the browser console. Them you should be able to figure out how to access the text bit you want. If that doesn't work, can you post your code?

Comment: i point wrong data, now its can function now :)......thank Henry , really appreciated your answer

Comment: Henry for size it is not working , this is sample , http://plnkr.co/edit/7UKIN3tPOgIrGFuJJzRr?p=preview
how to make it arrange base on frenquency ...sorry bad english im using , hope you understand

Comment: In that plunk, some words are not showing because they exceed the maximum word size (`font-size` and word length) that can fit inside you SVG element. If you increase the width (`var w = 400`) and height you'll get the words. however you should look to scale down the size with a scale as mentioned above.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "make it arrange base on frequency". the `doc_count` from your Elasticsearch terms aggregation will be frequency of that term appearing in your documents, and that gets converted to a size in the code from the answer. Is this a separate question?